# How to interrupt a GPIO RPi loop at any time with TKinter button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, raspberry-pi, gpio

This is the second version of a program I am struggling with.  I posted an earlier question with the first version of the program but had no luck.

Here is my "Big Picture Idea" in case it helps you find where I am going off track.  I have a lot of plants to water, and I want to make a GUI with TKinter that will appear on a touchscreen on a Raspberry Pi.  The Pi controls a 110V relay switch that is wired to a water pump.  Its just basic "on/off" loop for z # of plants.

The user has three slider bars to adjust, X, Y, and Z values. X is how long the water pump needs to be ON, Y is how long the water pump needs to be OFF (so you have time to physically move the hose to the next plant), and Z is the total number of plants you have to water.  I used to just let the loop run forever because I could always CTRL-C the program to end, but now I am trying to make it all on the touch-screen with no keyboard required - more user friendly than teaching someone who doesn't know what Linux means how to use a terminal.  It also needs to run like a program people are used to seeing, hence the GUI touch-screen buttons (like smart phones and tablets).

The code works well for the most part, it stops and starts without crashing. I figured out the start button, and there is a reset button to clear the slider values in case you want to start the values over at zeros.  But the BIG problem, which seems to be affecting many people here, is the friggin' EXIT button.

I need the user to be able to press a TKinter EXIT button at any time during the loop, and have the program know when the button is pressed and obey it immediately, basically interrupting the loop. I've tried many things, nothing works. Checkbuttons will only wait until the loop finishes, then update the toggle value.  At that point it's too late; I need user control during the entire watering loop.

I also don't want the program to quit when EXIT is pressed, rather, I want the GPIO loop to stop on the "OFF" value and basically reset the program to the beginning state.

I know that `time.sleep()` is very crude, but I have not found any other way to do it.  I've seen people talk about 'threading', I have no idea what that means and it sounds like I never will.  I've also seen people talk about TKinters' "after()" function, again, I need very clear examples for answers. Just saying "Use threading" provides no help - I'm a noob!

```
    from tkinter import *
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time


    master = Tk()


    def onoffcycle():
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.LOW)
        y=off.get()
        y=float(y)
        x=on.get()
        x=float(x)
        GPIO.output(14, True)
        print("On")+str(x)
        time.sleep(x)
        GPIO.output(14, False)
        print("Off")+str(y)
        time.sleep(y)


    def start():
        print("Prepare to water in 10 seconds...")
        time.sleep(10)
        z=cycle.get()
        z=float(z)
        while z > 0:
            onoffcycle()
            z=z-1
            print("Cycles remaining:")+str(z)
            ###tog()
            ###if t==1:
                ###reset()
        else:
            reset()
        ### this program runs onoffcycle() for z number of cycles as set by the slider.
        ### It should check for an exit toggle, then run the program for one cycle,
        ### then check for exit, then another round. countdown from cycle.get variable


    def reset():
        GPIO.cleanup()
        on.set(0)
        off.set(0)
        cycle.set(0)

    t=IntVar()

    ###def tog():
        ### HELP!  This is where I need the program to be looking for the EXIT button being pressed
        ### in order to stop the program.  Everything I have tried so far waits until the z value drops
        ### to zero, basically until the program stops on its own.  I need a button that interrupts
        ### everything.


    on = Scale(master, label="Set # Seconds Water ON:", from_=0, to=180, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=400, width=35,
              troughcolor="red", bg="SteelBlue1", fg="black", bd=6, sliderlength=90, sliderrelief=RIDGE,
               font = '-weight bold')
    on.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=3)

    off = Scale(master, label="Set # Seconds Water OFF:", from_=0, to=30, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=400, width=35,
              troughcolor="yellow", bg="SteelBlue1", fg="black", bd=6, sliderlength=90, sliderrelief=RIDGE,
                font = '-weight bold')
    off.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=3)

    cycle = Scale(master, label="Set # of Plants to Water:", from_=0, to=200, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=400, width=35,
              troughcolor="green", bg="SteelBlue1", fg="black", bd=6, sliderlength=90, sliderrelief=RIDGE,
                font = '-weight bold')
    cycle.grid(column=1, row=3, columnspan=3)


    go = Button(master, text="START", command=start, bg="SteelBlue3", width=10, height=2, font='-weight bold')
    go.grid(column=1, row=4)

    adios = Checkbutton(master, text="EXIT", variable=t, indicatoron=0, bd=6, bg="SteelBlue3", width=11, height=2, font='-weight bold')
    adios.grid(column=3, row=4)
    ###adios should have a command to run an exit program - with toggle values? or something else?
    resetbutton = Button(master, text="RESET", command=reset, bg="SteelBlue3", width=10, height=2, font='-weight bold')
    resetbutton.grid(column=2, row=4)



    mainloop()
```

Comment: you have to use `root.after(milliseconds, function_name)` instead of `sleep()` and `while`. `10s = 10000ms` so ie, `root.after(10000, start)` at the end of `start()` should run this function again after 10s and you don't need `sleep()` and you don't need `while` but `if` to stop `after`.

Comment: `print("On")+str(x)` makes no sense because `print` returns `None` so you do `None+str(x)`. Maybe you need `print("On", x)` or at least `print( "On "+str(x) )` or `print( "On {}".format(x) )` but first version is the simplest.

Comment: furas - thanks for so much info! The print() parts do print the users' chosen values on the command line; I suppose it really is not meant to be seen by the user, since I want the TKinter window to be fullscreen.  I've been using it while debugging, and it may not be useful in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use boolean variables `True/False` to control loops and other elements

For example, create global variable

```
time_to_exit = False
```

and set it `True` when you press `EXIT` button

and use in function

```
while z > 0 and not time_to_exit:
```

It should stops loop.

You can use other boolean variables to inform program if loop was stoped and it can exit.

```
# inform function to use global variable
global loop_is_working
loop_is_working = True
while z > 0 and not time_to_exit:

# ...

def reset():
  # inform function to use global variable
  global loop_is_working

  loop_is_working = False

def on_exit:

   if loop_is_working:
       reset()
       # check again afte 100ms
       after(100, on_exit)
   else:
       # stop `mainloop()` and close tkinter window
       root.destroy()
```

---

Your other problem is: you use `sleep()` and `while` so `Tkinter` has to wait till it ends.

You can use `master.after(miliseconds, function_name)` and `Tkinter/mainloop` will execute this function and meanwhile it can check your buttons.

example

```
time_to_exit = False

def start():
    print("Prepare to water in 10 seconds...")

    # mainloop will run `start_loop` after `10s`
    master.after(10000, start_loop) # 10s = 10 000ms 

def start_loop():    
    z = float(cycle.get())
    loop(z)
    # or
    #master.after(0, loop, z)

def loop(z):    
    if z > 0 and not time_to_exit:
        onoffcycle()
        z -= 1
        print("Cycles remaining:", z)
            ###tog()
            ###if t==1:
                ###reset()
        # mainloop will run `loop` again as soon as possible
        master.after(0, loop, z)
     else:    
        reset()
```

or even

```
# create global variables
time_to_exit = False
loop_is_working = False

def start():
    # inform function to use global variable
    global loop_is_working

    loop_is_working = True

    print("Prepare to water in 10 seconds...")

    # mainloop will run `start_loop` after `10s`
    master.after(10000, start_loop) # 10s = 10 000ms 

def start_loop():    
    z = float(cycle.get())
    loop(z)
    # or
    #master.after(0, loop, z)

def loop(z):    

    if z > 0 and not time_to_exit and loop_is_working:
        onoffcycle()
        z -= 1
        print("Cycles remaining:", z)
            ###tog()
            ###if t==1:
                ###reset()
        # mainloop will run `loop` again as soon as possible
        master.after(0, loop, z)
     else:    
        reset()

def reset():
  # inform function to use global variable
  global loop_is_working

  # ... your code ...

  loop_is_working = False
```

Comment: This is great, I'll try it out and let you know!

Comment: Wow!  The reset button now interrupts the loop!!!  The only problem now, is that the 'z' value doesn't decrease after each iteration of 'loop()'.  Should it be moved, or introduced as a global variable?  It seems to me that it might be getting the value from the button each time as the loop is played...

Comment: I change code - now there is `start_loop` which get `z` (after 10s) and run `loop(z)`. And `after` run `loop` again with new `z`

Answer (score 0):

So here is the new code with furas' excellent suggestions.  I also found out how to get `z` value to decrease with each iteration. The RESET button will now halt the program after it completes the current cycle, and wait for you to start a new cycle.  This is because I still have `time.sleep()` handling the ON and OFF timing.  I tried to use `after()` for this but it kept leading to other bigger problems.  And at this point, the program is technically completely usable, so I don't mind it hanging for one cycle; it doesn't impair with the real world application!  I still have other issues with it that deserve their own questions, such as configurating the touchscreen to calibrate properly, and starting the program automatically after auto-starting LDXE.  I plan on placing everything properly in a `class()`.  Also would like to be able to change the Label widget text while stuck in an `if:` statement.  Thanks everyone!

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    from Tkinter import *
    import ttk
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time


    master = Tk()
    master.title("Obligatory Title")
    master.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    time_to_exit = False
    loop_is_working = False


    def onoffcycle():
        global t
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
        y=float(off.get())
        x=float(on.get())
        GPIO.output(18, True)
        print("On")+str(x)
        t.set("Water ON")
        t.get()
        time.sleep(x)
        GPIO.output(18, False)
        print("Off")+str(y)
        t.set("Water OFF")
        time.sleep(y)             

    def start():
        global loop_is_working
        global t
        loop_is_working = True
        print("Prepare to water in 10 seconds...")
        t.set("Prepare to water in 10 seconds...")
        master.after(10000, loop)

    def loop():
        z=float(cycle.get())
        global loop_is_working
        global time_to_exit
        global t
        t.set("Now Watering...")
        if z > 0 and not time_to_exit and loop_is_working:
            onoffcycle()
            z=z-1
            cycle.set(z)
            print("Cycles remaining: ")+ str(z)
            master.after(0, loop)
        else:
            reset()


    def reset():
        global loop_is_working

        GPIO.cleanup()
        on.set(0)
        off.set(0)
        cycle.set(0)
        t.set("Welcome!  Drag the sliders to set values. Tap left or right of the sliders to fine tune values.")
        loop_is_working = False

    t = StringVar()
    t.set("Welcome!  Drag the sliders to set values. Tap left or right of the sliders to fine tune values.")

    welcome = Label(master, bg="Steelblue3", bd=6, relief=RAISED, width=92,
                    height=2, textvariable=t)
    welcome.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=3)


    on = Scale(master, label="Set # Seconds Water ON:", from_=0, to=120, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=735,
               width=50, troughcolor="steelblue", bg="SteelBlue1", fg="black", bd=6, sliderlength=90,
               sliderrelief=RIDGE)
    on.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=3)

    off = Scale(master, label="Set # Seconds Water OFF:", from_=0, to=30, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=735,
                width=50,troughcolor="steelblue", bg="SteelBlue1", fg="black", bd=6, sliderlength=90,
                sliderrelief=RIDGE)
    off.grid(column=1, row=3, columnspan=3)

    cycle = Scale(master, label="Set # of Plants to Water:", from_=0, to=200, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=735,
                  width=50,troughcolor="steelblue", bg="SteelBlue1", fg="black", bd=6, sliderlength=90,
                  sliderrelief=RIDGE)
    cycle.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=3)

    go = Button(master, text="START", command=start, bg="green3", width=19, height=3,
                bd=4, font='-weight bold')
    go.grid(column=1, row=5)

    adios = Button(master, text="EXIT", command=exit, bg="red3", width=19, height=3,
                bd=4, font='-weight bold')
    adios.grid(column=3, row=5)

    resetb = Button(master, text="RESET", command=reset, bg="yellow3", width=19,
                height=3, bd=4, font='-weight bold')
    resetb.grid(column=2, row=5)

    mainloop()
```